# error when changing background color in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issue in changing the background color in a dataframe, following what is described here: https://newbedev.com/how-to-use-python-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-column

My approach: i am creating an index of 0 and 1 in order to get the color I need, then I set this index to a new dataframe and apply the coloring function

```
color_index = []
for x in range(len(sql_query.cp)):
    if cod_port.index(sql_query.cp[x]) % 2 == 0:
        color_index.append(0)
    else:
        color_index.append(1)

sql_query['Index'] = color_index
table = sql_query.set_index('Index')

def highlight(df):
    if df.index == 0:
        return ['background-color: white']*9
    else:
        return ['background-color: grey']*9

table.style.apply(highlight,axis=1)
```

I get this error message:

```
ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.
```

sample of table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byK5Z.png)

I don't understand it considering that table has index or 0 or 1 for any of its rows.
I have also try with a column of 0 and 1 (instead of using the index) but it gives me same error message.

Couldn't find any other useful solution here on stack or anywhere else.

Comment: Sample of the dataframe would be helpful.

Comment: @HenryEcker I edited the question with a sample of table

Comment: To generate that error pandas performs a check: `df.index.is_unique` and `df.columns.is_unique`. If either of those are `False` you get the error. Try evaluating those before you call `df.style`. You can use `df.index.duplicated` to track down the culprits: the Error message given seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I agree error message seems pretty clear, but unfortunately I was not able to solve it.